# How to update libstdc++ ( version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found) with no root?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, cmake, libstdc++

I updated my gcc to 4.9+ while there's no `GLIBCXX_3.4.20` in `/lib64/libstdc++.so.6`, and it encounters error: version *`GLIBCXX_3.4.20 not found`*.

In the new gcc I installed locally, I can find `gcc_installed/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.20`, but is there any method to update the libstdc++ without root? Or alternative way to handle this problem?

Comment: Read up on rpath, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, etc. You can start with the manual of `ld.so`. Your question is not specific enough, so it is unlikely to get a helpful answer.

Comment: Related, [Undefined reference to mempcy@GLIBC_2.14 when compiling on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12286460/608639). Be sure the symbols are ABI compatible. I'm not sure if you can "symbol version" your way out of the problem.