# Undefined reference to memcpy@glibc_2.14 while trying to use an external library

Tags: c++, linux, glibc, memcpy

When compiling a C++program which uses an external library I face

> "undefined reference to `memcpy@GLIBC_2.14`" error in linking phase.

First, let me say that I have taken a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286460/undefined-reference-to-mempcyglibc-2-14-when-compiling-on-linux) and implemented the solution (the version.c file thing) and it didn't work for me.

I checked the library so file with this command:
`objdump -T libVimbaCPP.so | grep -i glibc_2.14`

and result was:
`0000000000000000      DF *UND* 0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.14  memcpy`

What are my options here?

Is there something wrong with that library because it has reference to `GLIBC_2.14`?

Or do I need to change something on my side?

Thank You

Comment: What version of glibc do you have installed on your system? `ldd --version` or `/usr/lib64/libc.so.6` ?

Comment: Can't you update or compile the library yourself? It seems you are trying to link a library linked against a different version of glibc you have.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linking against an old version of libc to provide greater application coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4032373/608639), [Undefined reference to mempcy@GLIBC_2.14 when compiling on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12286460/608639), etc.