# glibc versioned symbol and undefined reference to memcpy@GLIBC_2.14

Tags: glibc, libc

Today, when I use conda zlib to compile a binary, I encountered the error `Undefined reference to memcpy@GLIBC_2.14`.

```
.../x86_64-conda-linux-gne/bin/ld: ...envs/myenv/lib/libz.so: undefined reference to memcpy@GLIBC_2.14
```

Although somebody asked similar questions, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286460/undefined-reference-to-mempcyglibc-2-14-when-compiling-on-linux), they cannot solve my problem since I am using third party library.

I then try to understand what is happening. I did the following experiments:

```sh
~ $ ldd $CONDA_PREFIX/lib/libz.so
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcc4a90000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe449c1a000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe449e70000)

~ $ nm $CONDA_PREFIX/lib/libz.so | grep memcpy
U memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14   

~ $ nm -gD /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep ' memcpy'
00000000000c7a30 T memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5
00000000000ad1e0 i memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14
```

### Q1: `@@` vs `@` in the versioned symbols

Why does `nm libz.so` above show `memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14` instead of `memcpy@GLIBC_2.14`.

From [all-about-symbol-versioning](https://maskray.me/blog/2020-11-26-all-about-symbol-versioning), I learnt that `@@` is the default to be used if a symbol without version is requested. But If the `libz.so` explicitly asks for `memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14`, shouldn't the error be `undefined reference to memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14`?

### Q2: what does `i` mean in the output. `man nm` says

> For ELF format files this indicates that the symbol is an indirect function.  This is a GNU extension to the standard set of ELF symbol types.  It indicates a symbol which if referenced by a relocation does not evaluate to its address, but instead must be invoked at runtime.  The runtime execution will then return the value to be used in the relocation.

But I cannot understand what it means.

- Does the `libc.so` I have provide `memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14` for others to link against?

### Q3: why my following code does not depend on symbol `memcpy`

I then coded a simple `foo.c` file

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char from[10] = "hello";
    char to[10] = "";
    printf("from <%s> to <%s>\n", from, to);
    memcpy(to, from, 10);
    printf("from <%s> to <%s>\n", from, to);
}
```

Compiling it `gcc -c foo.c` and then `nm foo.o`, I see the following:

```
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000000 T main
                 U printf
```

It has `U printf`, but not `U memcpy`. Why? Is this related to the `i` type in **Q**?

### Q4: why adding `__asm__` has no effect

I added a line `__asm__(".symver memcpy,memcpy@GLIBC_2.14");` to `foo.c`, the result is the same. I then changed it to one of the following. Strangely, all of them will be compiled successfully, even some of them contains various typos.

- `__asm__(".symver memcpy,memcpy@GLIBC_2.14");`
- `__asm__(".symver memcpy,memcpy@GLIBC_2.18");`  2.18 does not exist
- `__asm__(".symver memcpy,xxxxxx@GLIBC_2.18");`

It seems it has no effect for `memcpy`. I tested it for other functions like `foo,foo@v1` and it works only if `foo@v1` exists as an exported symbol. So I think the syntax and mechanism for versioned symbols is correct when `foo` is used; but `memcpy` is special.

How to explain this?

Answer (score 1):

As for Q3, I think it's because gcc is inlining its builtin version of memcpy. You have to pass -fno-builtin to gcc to force the use of libc's memcpy. Not sure if Q4 is also related to this.

I'm also looking for answers to the other questions. It's not relevant, but the reason libc has multiple memcpy versions is to guarantee backwards compatibility with programs that use memcpy with overlapping regions.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Good idea. I had the same undefined reference to memcpy@GLIBC_2.14. But unfortunately, it was in a pre-compiled library that was included into the project. So I could not re-compile it with -fno-builtin. Howver, I just exited the conda environment and re-ran `make` to finish the linker step against the newer gcc builtins that the library expected.